# What is the business implication of Hyperledger Fabric ledger metrics?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Hyperledger Fabric metrics (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metrics_reference.html) has three metrics:ledger_block_processing_time, ledger_blockstorage_commit_time and ledger_statedb_commit_time. My questions are:

1. What does ledger_block_processing_time mean in terms of business? Does it refer to the process of putting multiple transactions into a block by orderer?Does it include subsequent process in which blocks are submitted by peers?
2. ledger_blockstorage_commit_time and ledger_statedb_commit_time look similar, what is the difference between them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Q 2:
The ledger has 2 parts, first is the actual blockchain/blockstorage, and the second is stateDB, which represents the current world-state. First metrics is commit time in blockstorage, second one is commit time in stateDB.